# Referenced Notebook not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

I'm given a `notebook` to run in `Azure Databricks`. I imported the notebook to my user folder `Workspace\Users\MyUserName@CompanyName.com`. Following command in the notebook gives the error shown below.

**Question**: Where is the referenced notebook `qc_notebook` located in Databricks?

My notebook that I am running following command on is at  `Workspace\Users\MyUserName@CompanyName.com` location in Databricks:

```
%run ../../qc_functions
```

Error:

> Notebook not found: qc_functions. Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.
> **Stacktrace**:
> /Users/MyUserName@CompanyName.com/myNotebook: python

Comment: What is the type of notebook you imported? is it `.ipynb`

Comment: @JayashankarGS The notebook type is `.py`

Answer (score 0):

**`%run`** only supports to run databricks notebooks and not for python script files(`.py`)

When you import `.py` file it automatically converts it to notebook type,
try checking it if it is still showing as `.py` then follow below steps to convert it.

[image]

Convert the script file as notebook by adding below comments in it.

```
# Databricks notebook source
```

Add above comment at the starting of the file, and

```
# COMMAND ----------
```

For creating cell.

Below is the code i have added in my `.py` file and imported it in databricks workspace.

```py
# Databricks notebook source

# COMMAND ----------
print("hi")
```

If it is converted to notebook type, then run below command.

```
%run /Users/xxx@xxxxx.com/file_name
```

Output:
[image]

Refer [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/vscode-ext/dev-tasks/python-notebook-job.html) for more information.